# IAP in iOS stopped working

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

We are using Unibill in Unity to make In-App purchases for iOS
this have been working for more than one month , we were testing and everything works fine on iOS (we have android as well and it's working)

the items we added were on waiting for app submission , because we haven't submitted any new version of the app to itunes connect

after we submitted a new version for review it was accepted and the in app items status changed to accepted as well .

at this point we stopped being able to purchase the items from either sandbox or testflight , StoreKit is returning no items at all

I'am 99% sure the error is not related to the code because we haven't changed anything for more than a month and we were able to purchase perfectly

the only 2 changes are:
 * the app was accepted , the consumable items status changed to accepted as well
 * not sure if this is related but we renewed our developer account in the member center 2 days ago , not sure if this is related to the problem in anyway

any ideas about this problem?? can you really not test the purchase after it's accepted anymore?

thanks in advance

Comment: OMG Hassan, you HAVE TO CHANGE TO Unity's own built-in IAP/IAB.  it's magic.

Comment: I know , we are planning to move to it soon , but we have bugs when we update unity we are still on unity 5.2.5 which doesn't have IAP, so we are going to do this next release . could the problem be in the plugin? it was working for a while

Comment: Just purely FWIW.  Based on moving whole companies to the latest Unity.  You should honestly just FORGET the old version of the app, and go ahead and update.  Go here ... http://forum-old.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iap-store-guides-amazon-apple-google-play-windows.372647/page-3#post-2565610 ... for some excellent starter code written by some whizzes  ;-)

Comment: I used unity IAP today, same thing , works fine on android , product unavailable in ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no Idea what solved the problem , it seems that it was something from apple's side

it wasn't working for 3 days, and it started working the fourth day without changing anything in the project!

I did add a new item for purchase in the itunesconnect , could it be the reason? it might have refreshed something? I don't know